# Появляющийся div + своя карта из конструктора гугл = треш?

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь, совет. В конструкторе карт от гугла создал карту, открыл доступ, определил область видимости, получил код для сайта. А далее самое интересное. Если просто вставить карту на страницу - все норм. Пашет как надо. Но если вставить в появляющийся див, то карта съезжает. Область видимости не показывается в центре фрейма. Просто уезжает на максимальное удаление и все. Вот пример простой.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="link1" href="#">Click me</a>
<br>
<iframe id="content1" style="display: none;" src="http://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1XCQgM2Ze65XdUGyu4uzcE-NlAKI" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {$('a#link1').click(function (e) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('#content1').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();});
        $('body').click(function () {
            var link = $('a#link1');
            if (link.hasClass('active')) {
                link.click();}});});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

У кого есть знания как побороть эту какаху - поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: всему помеха display: none

Comment: Допустим. И как по-вашему мне сделать ее выпадающей? Хоть намекните что-ли) Яндекс например нормально хавает. Проблем с ним вообще нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много способов, первое что на ум пришло, абсолютное позиционирование за пределами экрана, думаю можно легко придумать еще пяток способов.

Как вариант: сначала загрузить карту, а уж затем скрыть. Наверное мелькнет на экране.

Либо вообще ничего не грузить до нажатия кнопки (не подключать ифрейм), а динамически загрузить его по нажатию кнопки.

```js
$(function() {

  $('a#link1').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#content1').toggleClass('noview');
  });

});
```

```css
.noview {
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a id="link1" href="#">Click me</a></p>

<iframe id="content1" class="noview" src="http://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1XCQgM2Ze65XdUGyu4uzcE-NlAKI" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim non rerum voluptates voluptatem aspernatur cumque quaerat sed impedit dolore natus quis officia harum, eum repellendus neque fuga reprehenderit magni, id.</p>
```

Comment: благодарю Вас! Если подкинете еще идей на будущее - вообще поклон до земли.